# two commands be implemented same time for each item of list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of links and I am trying to execute two commands for each item of the list before executing those commands for next item of the list. 
This is what I have so far:

```
 set max-links sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-in-links [label]] of turtles
     foreach max-links
      [
        the-links -> ask the-links [show end1]
      ask the links [ask end1 [ask my-out-links with [not member? self max-links] [die]]]
      ask the links  [ask end2 [ask my-in-links with [not member? self max-links] [die]]]
    ]
```

the problem right now is that the commands first begin to execute for all end1 in the entire list then for end2, whereas I want both commands execute for each item before moving on to the next item of list

Comment: How do you know all the `end1`s are being executed before the `end2`s?  Aside from a typo (`the links` should be `the-links`), I think the problem is one of logic, not command structure.  The three asks should be executed for the each link in the list before getting to the next link.  

However, the turtle at `end1` of the first link in the list, will ask all its other out-links that are in `max-links` to die.  Other links in `max-links` may have the same `end1`, but by the time the `for-each` gets to them, they may no longer exist.  Is this the problem you are encountering?

Comment: no that is not the problem I'm encountering. when i run the function i get no error regarding "link doesn't exist". I compare the results with my hand written algorithm and I see that if it was running correctly, no agent should be able to give 2 out links

Comment: It would be helpful, then, to show us what you get vs. what you expect.